# Migrating Custom Function Jar from 11G to 12C

Tags: soa, weblogic12c

We have custom functions implemented in 11G. We are upgrading our servers to 12C.
At this point; my custom functions are not recognized.

All custom functions are in a jar file. This jar is in the same directory as the oracle.soa.ext.jar that contains the manifest for the path.

The contents of that manifest.mf are:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.2
Created-By: 1.8.0_40-ea-b08 (Oracle Corporation)
Implementation-Vendor: Oracle
Implementation-Title: Oracle SOA EXT
Implementation-Version: 12.1.2
Product-Name: Oracle SOA EXT
Product-Version: 12.1.2.0.0
Specification-Version: 11.1.1
Extension-Name: oracle.soa.ext
Class-Path: f17UserDefinedFunctions.jar classes
```

This has been working for some time in 11G but I am getting "not found" errors trying to use custom functions in 12C.

We are on Linux servers.

Is there a difference in 12C that I need to be aware of?

Comment: Well.... this is depressing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are still working with Oracle to resolve an issue but discovered along the way that we *were* loading the extended xPath functions just fine.

The problem is deeper in. A couple of the actual functions don't seem to be working properly on the new server.

Since the actual issue is not related to the question - I thought it should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

We migrated BPEL services from 10g to 12c, the services contained embedded Java and imported Java libraries. When we launched Maven build, it failed with "not found" error. The issue was that the libraries were not accessible during the build phase.

I used a workaround described in [this blog](http://www.avioconsulting.com/blog/building-soa-12c-projects-include-java-code-maven//) -- it works fine for us. Just make sure the external libraries are not bundled into the final service JAR (SAR) by excluding them from the packaging.

Comment: I'll look at that for the next round of imports in the upgrade.

I'm still not clear on what our issue is. I send a test project and the extended xPath jar to oracle and everything works for them.

I'll post the final results here when we get it sorted.